# Eliminating backslashes from JavaScript strings

Tags: javascript

Using JavaScript I would like to eliminate `\`.
Currently I get back `\"Sequence\"`, but would like to remove `\` and get `"Sequence"` instead. 
Tried `*.replace(/\\/g, '');`, but it did not work.

Comment: How are you looking at the value?

Comment: `yourString.replace("\","");`

Comment: There's no space in the language name, it's `Javascript`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember, in JavaScript `\` is an escape character.  So when you say

```
\"Sequence\"
```

I'm guessing the string is actually `"<double quote>Sequence<double quote>"`

In other words, there *is no* back slash for you to remove.

---

Or, if I'm reading the question wrongly, note that `replace` does **NOT** modify the string in question.  So you wouldn't do

```
foo.replace(/\\/g, '');
```

but rather

```
foo = foo.replace(/\\/g, '');
```

Comment: @WesleyMurch - maybe.  In this case though there **really is** no backslash - at least I don't think, based on the limited details OP provided.

Comment: @WesleyMurch - or maybe my second guess is better.  In either case, this is the answer you want to upvote - *waves hand* ;)